# Grails Cassandra ORM

Tags: grails, orm, cassandra

I am trying to persist a domain object in Grails to Cassandra database using Cassandra ORM plugin. I have successfully persisted it to H2 using GORM before, however I want to give Cassandra a try.

The object is defined as follows:

```
    package gibb1

class newCassa {
    UUID uuid
    String name
    String score

     static cassandraMapping = [
            primaryKey: "uuid", // Want "payID" primaryKey, but right now it might not even be present.
            explicitIndexes: ["name"]           
    ]
}
```

However I get following error:

```
| Error 2013-04-18 11:04:16,533 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR CassandraOrmGrailsPlugin  - Exception adding ORM methods to gibb1.newCassa
```

I am posting the question here because I could not find the contact info of the developer of the plugin:
https://github.com/bflorian/cassandra-orm

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

With the cassandra ORM plugin you have to manually create the column families, if those are not created correctly it will throw odd errors.

Have you created any of the column families?

Comment: Hi Jeff,
I was trying to follow the guide, but it is not very detailed:
http://www.florian.org/grails/cassandra-orm/docs/guide/single.html#3%20Demo%20Data%20Model
I started from scratch after encountering errors. I created the "User"m "User_IDX" and "User_CTR", but I did not specify the structure of the tables. Now when I try to store or retrieve information I get "null".
Are you familiar with the plug-in. Can you help me create tables for a trivial example? For example domain object with just a KEY and a field.
Any help is greatly appreciated!